# How to use execve or execvp to print $PATH

Tags: c, system-calls

When I use terminal to run `echo $PATH` command, it will show the PATH environment variable.

For example, something like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

However, when I use `execvp()` to call it, it will only print the string "$PATH".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    char* a[] = {"echo", "$PATH", NULL};
    execvp("echo", a);
    exit(0);
}
```

The output is: `$PATH`.

How could I use `execvp()` to echo environment variables correctly?

Comment: what's wrong with `getenv` ?

Comment: Check the third parameter of `main`, by gaining access to the array of pointers to chars, you will get the values of environment variables. Or use, `extern char **environ;` accessing it is left as an exercise.

Comment: Variable expansion is done by the shell, not by the program. In other words, `bash` understands "$..." notation, `echo` does not.

Comment: Wrong `system-calls` tag. They are OS specific and listed (for Linux) on [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: the `echo` runs under the shell, therefore, the new process should be the new shell and pass parameters to the new shell of "echo $PATH" and NULL.  also, this line: `execvp("echo", a);` should be: `execvp( a[0], a );`   where `a[0]' should be a pointer `"/bin/sh".   Note: if the OS is windows, the parameter list in `a[]` would be different.  I.E. "cmd", "-c", "echo $PATH", NULL

Answer (score 3):

`execvp` won't run a shell, so env. variables won't be evaluated.

Using `system` would work because it runs commands in a shell:

```
system("echo $PATH");
```

although for this particular case the simplest & cleanest would be `getenv` (which is also more portable: also works on Windows)

```
const char *value = getenv("PATH");
if (value!=NULL)
{
   puts(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The usage of the third parameter to `main`, is how to obtain the environment variables used. When the runtime loader executes the code, the argument count, arguments and environment variables are passed into the startup.

The output would contain a string that has environment variable name and value that is delimited by an `=`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp){
    while (*envp){
        printf("%s\n", *envp++);
    }
}
```

For example, see this [ideone snippet](https://ideone.com/YnMmrb)

Result would be similar as:

> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

**Edit:** Instead of looping through all the environment variables, just to get one, use `strstr` to find the string that contains `PATH`, then, add the length of the string "PATH=" to the pointer retuned from `strstr` will yield the value for the environment variable `PATH`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp){
    while (*envp){
        char *ptrPath = strstr(*envp, "PATH");
        if (ptrPath) printf("%s\n", (ptrPath+5));
        *envp++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Second Edit:**

As @jonathanleffler pointed out my boo-boo, here's the edit, that is complete with string manipulate to get the exact match of the string "PATH".

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp){
    while (*envp){
        char *ptrPath = strstr(*envp, "PATH");
        char *exact = NULL;
        if (ptrPath){
            char *ptrDelim = strrchr(*envp, '=');
            if (ptrDelim){
                size_t ptrDelimLen = (ptrDelim - *envp + 1);
                exact = malloc(ptrDelimLen + 1);
                strncpy(exact, *envp, ptrDelimLen);
                exact[ptrDelimLen - 1]='\0';
                if (!strcmp(exact, "PATH") && strlen(exact) == 4){
                    printf("%s\n", (ptrPath+5));
                }
            }
        }
        *envp++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code would show all the environment variables, not just the one that the OP is interested in.  How would you go about modifying your code to only print (the value of) `$PATH`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the comment, have amended the answer to show how its done.

Comment: Hmmm; I think I’d be happier if you didn’t print `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too.

Comment: The second edit probably fixes the problem, but it seems rather complex. I was thinking of `while (*envp) { if (strncmp(*envp, "PATH=", sizeof("PATH=") - 1) == 0) printf("%s\n", (ptrPath+5)); *envp++; }` which is simpler and accurate.  We can debate the relative merits of `sizeof("PATH=") - 1` vs `5` (there's one of each in the code fragment for good measure), and so on, but that should be sufficient for a single fixed environment variable.  Generalizing to a list of environment variables to be printed is a tad harder, but not by much.

Comment: I believe a better answer is to use `getenv("PATH")`

Answer (score 2):

The `$` (in `$PATH`) is processed by a shell. Read about [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

If you just want to get the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))  use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) as `getenv("PATH")` (there is no need to use the third argument to `main`, as [answered by t0mm13b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118371/841108)).

If you insist in getting that by `execvp` you need to `exec` something like `/bin/sh -c "echo $PATH"` (so three non-null arguments to `execvp` in your `a`, the last non-null one being the `"echo $PATH"` string).

If you insist on showing all the environment variables (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)...) you might use the `extern char **environ;` global variable, or use the [env(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) program (without arguments) or the [printenv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html) one. The [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) startup routine would set up that `environ`.